# Why is Dragon inserting a json object into a hidden field

Tags: asp.net, webforms, naturallyspeaking

We are getting an error in an application that I have written inside a corporate customer.  the app is built in asp .net webforms.  We think we are getting an error from Dragon.  The error is: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{"protocol":"nuanria_messaging","type":"request","messageId":32,"action":"banejkelfpdmmmfobepfdnbmbbnecnol:activate","responseRequired":false}' to data type int.  I don't have access to the two users that get this error, but both are dragon users and they have confirmed that both have the problem.

I think that there is a hidden field that I use to hold an integer.  I think that dragon is overwriting the content in the hiddenfield, but I'm not 100% sure.  The hiddenfield is the only integer that I have.

Is there any thought on how to stop dragon from interfering in the browser?  I don't do support and don't have access to this user's desktop.  they have told me that the browser extension in chrome is disabled.  Any other ideas are appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is an answer, but here is the result.  We went to the browser extensions in chrome, disabled the dragon browser extension, restarted the browser, and the problem was resolved.  I don't have a better answer.  The users will accept this.